# Most efficient way to remove non-numeric list entries

Tags: python

I'm looking to 'clean' a list by excluding any items which contain characters other than 0-9, and wondering if there's a more efficient way than e.g.

```
import re
invalid = re.compile('[^0-9]')    
ls = ['1a', 'b3', '1']
cleaned = [i for i in ls if not invalid.search(i)]
print cleaned
>> ['1']
```

As I'm going to be operating on large-ish lists (5k items) of long strings (15 chars).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Anything wrong with the string method `isdigit` ?

```
>>> ls = ['1a', 'b3', '1']
>>> cleaned = [ x for x in ls if x.isdigit() ]
>>> cleaned
['1']
>>>
```

Comment: +1, another possibility would be `cleaned = filter(str.isdigit, ls)`

Comment: @eumiro, true, but that's both less Pythonic and also only works for exact `str` objects -- @MattH's solution works for `str`, `unicode`, and any other objects that have an `isdigit()` method (duck typing).

Answer (score 1):

You can use isnumeric function. It checks whether the string consists of only numeric characters. This method is present only on unicode objects. It won't work with integer or float values

```
myList = ['text', 'another text', '1', '2.980', '3']
output = [ a for a in myList if a.isnumeric() ]
print( output )      
# Output is : ['1', '3']
```

Ref: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isnumeric.htm

Answer (score -1):

In case one wants to keep both integers and floats in the output:

```
def is_float(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        return True
    except:
        return False

example_list = ['text', 'another text', '1', '2.980', '3']
output = [a for a in example_list if is_float(a)]
print(output)      
# Output is: ['1', '2.980', '3']
```

Alternatively, one can use `filter`, as [eumiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/449449/eumiro) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030082/most-efficient-way-to-remove-non-numeric-list-entries#comment6973075_6030118):

```
output = list(filter(is_float, example_list))
print(output)
# Output is: ['1', '2.980', '3']
```

---

Credit: `is_float()` comes from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16573822/395857) by [Saullo G. P. Castro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/832621/saullo-g-p-castro).