# List comprehension replacing items that are not float or int

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, python-3.3

I have a 2 item list.

Sample inputs:

```
['19(1,B7)', '20(1,B8)']
['16 Hyp', '16 Hyp']
['< 3.2', '38.3302615548213']
['18.6086945477694', '121.561539536844']
```

I need to look for anything that isn's a float or an int and remove it. So what I need the above list to look like is:

```
['19(1,B7)', '20(1,B8)']
['16 Hyp', '16 Hyp']
['3.2', '38.3302615548213']
['18.6086945477694', '121.561539536844']
```

I wrote some code to find '> ' and split the first item but I am not sure how to have my 'new item' take the place of the old:

Here is my current code:

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

for i in range(0,len(result_rows)):
    out_row = []
    for j in range(0,len(result_rows[i])-1):
        values = result_rows[i][j].split('+')
            for items in values:
                if '> ' in items:
                newItem=items.split()
                for numberOnly in newItem:
                   if is_number(numberOnly):
                      values.append(numberOnly)
```

The output of this (print(values)) is

```
['< 3.2', '38.3302615548213', '3.2']
```

Comment: You can append the new one and remove the old one by doing values.remove(items).

Comment: Yes, i've got a few lists, but just need to make sure i throw out any characters that arent numbers

Comment: Other than decimals, will you retain `-` as well? Are there other characters that you intend to keep that are possible in the strings?

Comment: How should you handle `123.23.23`?

Comment: More clarification: I don't think negative numbers will come into play, at least not any time soon. I believe I am dealing with only positive. my lists vary: some are [> 3.2, 235.4] or [235.4, < 3.2], so the less than or greater than can be the first or second item in the list, I am only working with pairs.

Comment: Also, do you want your output to actually remain in string form or in its natural int/float form?

Comment: I would like my output to be in string form..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more like a true list comprehension way to do what you want...

```
def isfloat(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        return True
    except:
        return False

[float(item) for s in mylist for item in s.split() if isfloat(item)]
#[10000.0, 5398.38770002321]
```

Or remove the `float()` to get the items as strings. You can use this list comprehension only if '>' or '<' are found in the string.

Comment: Can you write this in multi line?

Comment: `for s in mylist:`  `for item in s.split():`  `if isfloat(item):`   `float(item)`

Comment: No, else it wouldn't be a list comprehension

Comment: values = [> 1000, 456]  `[float(item) for s in values for item in s.split() if isfloat(item)]`

should output

`[1000, 456]` ? No 'print' statement needed?

Comment: @codefail when you do values =[list comprehension] the output will be stored in values. Put print ([list comprehension]) just for visualizing...

Comment: @codefail Sorry my fault... the 'isfloat()' was returning always `None` because I forgot the `return` commands, I updated the answer... thank for the code sample

Comment: @SaulloCastro Ahh, great, that did it - but I ran into something else I forgot to mention: I have values such as '1(1,A1)' which should be untouched - I suppose I need another 'if' statement to look for '>' or '<'

Comment: @codefail You should update your questions with the new assumptions. Could you include a case where you have this untouchables?

Comment: @SaulloCastro updated. Probably some redundancy but worked for the .csv files I am processing..

Comment: @codefail I thought you would to update only the problem description, and let the accepted answer with the solution. Usually, the answer that worked for you is toogled as accepted

Comment: How would this handle NoneType values?

Comment: @adivk the try/except block handles that, it will put a False where we have a NoneType value... and these will be ignored in the list comprehension

Comment: @SaulloCastro when I try to run this list comprehension on a list, it gives me the following error: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`

What could be going wrong?

Comment: @adivk you are right. It won't work in this case. The check `isfloat()` is only performed for `item`. In your case you need an extra check for `s`, to assert it is a string

Answer (score 0):

Iterators work well here:

```
def numbers_only(l):
    for item in l:
        if '> ' in item:
            item = item.split()[1]
        try:
            yield float(item)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

```
>>> values = ['> 10000', '5398.38770002321']
>>> list(numbers_only(values))
[10000.0, 5398.38770002321]
```

Normally, it's easier to create a new list than it is to iterate and modify the old list

Comment: I'm sorry, how do I implement this? print (numbers_only(values)) yields: <generator object numbers_only at 0x220fd4>

Comment: @codefail: Hence the call to `list(...)`. Note that you can do `for x in numbers_only(values): ...` without the conversion to a list

Comment: Im lost, i guess..if i try to do print list(numbers_only(values)) i get list object is not callable

Comment: @codefail That sounds like you have a variable called `list` somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I double checked, I do not.

Comment: @codefail: Ok, so what do you get from adding `print list` on the line above?

Comment: list object is not callable

Comment: Either you're not typing what I'm typing, or your environment is seriously messed up. I can run this code in a fresh console no problem. `print list` would not throw that exception - surely it prints out something? (`<type 'list'>` is what you should be, but aren't, getting)

Comment: Yeah, something is definitely off - I can't imagine that Python 3.3 is the reason why?

Comment: @Eric >>> `print(list)`  
`<class 'list'>`

Comment: Wasn't aware that py3k class them classes, but that shouldn't matter. Look, I don't know what you problem is, but [my code works fine](http://ideone.com/fDNHQA)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
def stip_chars(lst):
    for item in lst:
        yield item.strip("> ")

new_values = [v for v in strip_chars(values) if is_number(v)]
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the list in place rather than create a new list, you can iterate over it using `enumerate`:

```
for (list_index, item) in enumerate(values):
    if '> ' in item:
        values[list_index] = ' '.join(item_part for item_part in item.split() if is_number(item_part))
```

Or however you want to construct your new value - I'm not sure what you want if you have '5 6' in your original list.

If you want a new list, you can do something similar with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

```
values = ['> 10000', '5398.38770002321']
print [filter(lambda s: s in '0123456789.', v) for v in values]
```

RETURNS:

```
['10000', '5398.38770002321']
```

List of strings, as requested.

And to make it a function:

```
def parse_number(value):
    return [filter(lambda s: s in '0123456789.', v) for v in values]

print parse_number(values)
```

As an added bonus, making this accept negative numbers would be as easy as adding a hyphen to the whitelisted string `'0123456789.-'`

Comment: This gives me 'filter object at....'. I edited my code to give some more idea of what I've got

Comment: Are you typing it in exactly the same?  Here are the results from an online IDE: https://ideone.com/nJE1Sc

Comment: I must add that I am using Python 3.3