# How can I remove the number-free strings in a python list and convert it to a list of integers only?

Tags: python, list

I'm currently working on a school project, however I am having a hard time filtering a list that consists of strings as well as integers. The output of one such list looks like:

```
hours = ['Hours]', '58', '30', '44', '21', '18']
```

I have tried using to convert the strings in the list to integers using:

```
numhours = list(map(int, hours))
```

however, it fails once it sees the first string, since its not a number. How should I approach the problem of removing the strings that don't consist of numbers and convert the list to a list of integers that looks more like:

```
[58, 30, 44, 21, 18]
```

I appreciate the help

Comment: res = [int(ele) for ele in hours if ele.isdigit()]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would probably be to write a generator function, like so:

```
def only_integers(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        try:
            yield int(item)
        except ValueError:
            pass

numhours = list(only_integers(hours))
```

Answer (score 0):

`[int(hour) for hour in hours if hour.isdigit()]`

Comment: This works as long as you don't need negative integers.

Comment: However it turns out that it is the right answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030082/most-efficient-way-to-remove-non-numeric-list-entries

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the loop and try and turn each element to a int. If it does not work we can catch the error.

```
new = []
for elements in hours:
    try:new.append(int(elements))
    except:pass
```

output

```
[58, 30, 44, 21, 18]
```